# how to coverage write file func in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, file, junit

I made a simple function? to which I give a list of objects and then get their headers (just some strings), then sort and write to a file
when i made a test for this func, coverage was 0 lines and i dont know why

```
    public static void writeToFile(List<Appliances> appliances) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("\\result.csv")) {
            appliances.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Appliances::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            String previousClassName = "";

            for (var app : appliances) {
                if (!app.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(previousClassName)) {
                    writer.write(app.getHeaders());
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                    writer.write(app.toCSV());
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                    previousClassName = app.getClass().getSimpleName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so here is my unit test code, also I'm not native english speaker, dont write clever words pls, just a code and a little text would be a perfect solution, thanks a lot

```
@Test
    void writeToFile() throws Exception {

        try (FileReader expected = new FileReader(String.valueOf(path));
             BufferedReader expectedBR = new BufferedReader(expected);
             FileReader result = new FileReader(String.valueOf(path2));
             BufferedReader resultBR = new BufferedReader(result);
        ) {
            String line1;
            String line2;
            while ((line1 = expectedBR.readLine()) != null & (line2 = resultBR.readLine()) != null) {

                Assertions.assertEquals(line1, line2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be calling your `writeToFile(List<Appliances> appliances)` inside `@Test` to make it counted as coverage

Comment: can`t understand where to write it inside of test